# Local variable referenced before assignement

Tags: python, scope

I am going crazy.  This simple callback function doesn't recognize a variable assigned right before it in it's parent scope.  I get a `local variable 'elapsed' referenced before assignment` error`.  Why?

```
total = os.path.getsize(filename)
elapsed = 0

def progress_print(chunk):
    elapsed += len(chunk)  # elapsed is apparently unassigned??
    percent = float(elapsed) / float(total) * 100
    print '  Copied %s%%\033[A' % int(percent)

ftp.upload(filename, temp_path, callback=progress_print)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to assign to a global.  Python makes you *explicitly* do that.

```
def progress_print(chunk):
    global elapsed
    elapsed += len(chunk)
```

In general this is a pretty good sign that you need to refactor your code until you don't need globals any more.

Note that assignment and access are different beasts - the former requires you to explicitly declare globals, the latter does not.  Case in point, your `total` variable is another global but you do not attempt to assign to it, hence python does not complain.

The [Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) goes into more detail:

> **What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?**
>
> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are
>   implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere
>   within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local. If a variable
>   is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is
>   implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as ‘global’.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains
>   this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a
>   bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was
>   required for all global references, you’d be using global all the
>   time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in
>   function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would
>   defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying
>   side-effects.

Comment: I don't see why it needs to be a global.  The `total` variable is not a global and it is referenced within the callback function without any problem.  I don't get it :(

Comment: your `total` variable **is** a global, but you only access it, you don't attempt to assign to it.  That's the difference.  Only assignment requires explicit global declaration.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  However, if I declare `elapsed` as a global within the callback function, then `+=` will always yield the same result, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "same result."

Comment: @roippi: He would run into this problem even without globals by the way, i.e. a nested function referencing a variable in the parent function scope.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.. Thanks very much for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a

```
def progress_print(chunk):
    elapsed += len(chunk)
```

Here elapsed is the new local variable. Since you are doing a +=, which is nothing but:

```
elapsed = elapsed + len(chunk)
```

Here, elapsed is not initialized with any value, that is why you get the error - referenced before assignment.

Hence you need to do:

```
def progress_print(chunk):
    global elapsed
    elapsed += len(chunk)
```